# Move up subviews based on size of UITextView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView that changes height when the user types in multiple lines of text.  My problem is that when the user types in enough lines, the UITextView gets covered up by the UITableView that is located above the textview.  Is there any way to move the tableview up programmatically when the textview increases in height?

This is what changes the height of the textview, which is located in the textViewDidChange function:

```
if (self.contentSize.height > self.frame.height && self.contentSize.height < 166){
        self.frame.origin.y -= (self.contentSize.height - self.frame.height)
        self.frame.size = self.contentSize
    }else if (self.contentSize.height < self.frame.height){
        self.frame.origin.y += self.frame.height - self.contentSize.height
        self.frame.size = self.contentSize
    }
```

Comment: I tried moving the textview's superview up every time the textview resized, but that moves the textview up with the tableview... So that's definitely not the answer haha

Comment: Why not just move up the frame of the tableview?

Comment: Because I'm trying to make a messaging application... It doesn't look very nice if the tableview is too high

Comment: But you asked "Is there any way to move the tableview up programmatically when the textview increases in height?"

Comment: i just wrote an app with an iMessage style textview, its that what you are looking to do, where it sits at the bottom and then animates up with the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm aiming for...

Comment: Did you run into trouble with this when you wrote your app?

Comment: Just to clarify, when your textView covers the tableview, if you try scrolling to the bottom when the keyboard is up will the bottom be visible?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the tableview covers the top of the textview

Comment: Ok ya then try what's listed below.  Unless there are ambiguous or conflicting constraints, it should work.  You could also put the textview above the tableView in the layout heirarchy by making it appear above the tableView in the left-pane of IB, but using the constraint is the "right" way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, you could do this pretty easily just using NSLayoutConstraints, you could also do that it in code, but it would be much easier in stroyboard. If the textview was on the bottom, you would ctrl-drag from it to the tablview and use vertical spacing.  For the iMessage style textview, use the pin the textview to the bottom of the VC view with a layout constrain, and pin the top of it to the bottom of the tableview.  You will have to register for UIKeyBoardWillHide and UIKeyboardWillShow in your VC.  And then implement a method like the bottom one.   you can add the observers in viewDidAppear, and remove them in viewWillDisappear.  The height variable in the following method refers to a constraint i set on the height of the textView, the bottomConstraint is an IBOutlet to the bottomConstraint of my textView set in storyboard.

`
    func keyboardToggle(notification: NSNotification) {

```
    let info:AnyObject = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().height
    let duration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as Double

    var height:CGFloat!
    var botConst: CGFloat!


    switch notification.name {

    case UIKeyboardWillShowNotification:
        height = textView.contentSize.height
        botConst = keyboardHeight

    case UIKeyboardWillHideNotification:
        height = 40.0
        botConst = 0.0
        characterCountLabel.hidden = true
                bottomConstraint.constant = botConst
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    delegate.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.delegate.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
```

`

Comment: I assume you mean "interface builder" and not "storyboard" since you can also do so with xibs?

Comment: That resizes the height of my textview until I add text to it... Maybe I did it wrong though. I can try again

Comment: An NSLayoutConstraint will be the easiest way, whether you opt to do it in code or ib. Yes you can also do it in a xib, but storyboards are much more beginner friendly.

Comment: It should not affect the height of your textView, unless you are setting that constraint.  The only downside i have noticed using constraints is that if set a max height on the textview in bounces when reached.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach from the answer above.  I used the NSNotificationCenter to send a notification that text had been entered into the textview, then I updated the size of the textview and updated the y coordinate of the tableview.

This is the function that updates the position of my textview and the tableview:

```
func keyPressed(sender: NSNotification) {

    if let text = textView{
        if let messages = messageViews{

            if (text.contentSize.height > text.frame.height){
                messages.frame.origin.y -= (text.contentSize.height - text.frame.height)
                text.frame.origin.y -= (text.contentSize.height - text.frame.height)
                text.frame.size = text.contentSize
            }else if(text.contentSize.height < text.frame.height){
                messages.frame.origin.y += (text.frame.height - text.contentSize.height)
                text.frame.origin.y += (text.frame.height - text.contentSize.height)
                text.frame.size = text.contentSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, it's great that you are trying things on your own, that's the only way to learn, but I feel that caused more harm than good by mentioning NSNotifications.  The first method you were using was a delegate method, textViewDidChange, and that was the right place to handle this.  It took me a while to wrap my head around delegation, so I'll try to use a simple analogy.  Imagine your in your car. Every car in the vicinity can tune their radio to channel 100 and hear the same message, this is a Notifcation and it is a one to many. Now your car also has a gas sensor that sends a message to..

Comment: This was the only way I could get it to work... The constraints were not working for me. But maybe I set them up the wrong way. Are the constraints a delegate method? I'm quite new to this, so forgive my ignorance

Comment: your dashboard.  No other car can see this and no other car really cares how much gas you have, this is delegation, a one to one.  I guess you could argue in your case that the tableView also cares, but really the viewController is the only one that cares, it is the "delegate".  Im just informing you of the "standard" way to do this in iOS, But the beauty of programming is that you can be creative, so do what you think is best for you; eventually though as you get better, you should try and focus more on standards.

Comment: I understand.  The delegation I am talking about is the relationship between the textView and the ViewController.  Like I said, in the beginning when your learning, making it work is usually more important that doing it "right.," so don't worry too much, but check out the links  [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) and [constraints](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1), The second one is a great site for learning, and you should check out some of their tutorials.